# Android Date.from() taking device timezone into account?

Tags: android, date, java-time, java.util.date, datetime-conversion

Using the following code in Java8 -

`newTable.LogDate = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.of(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("GMT")).toInstant());`

The `LogDate` is ending up adjusted for my (and my user's) devices.

In the above case, for example, if I send it `1934, 1, 1` (Jan 1st, 1934), the LogDate has Dec 31st, 1933, 7pm. (For my device's Eastern US timezone.)

Is there a way to have the Date object NOT take the device's timezone and do any conversion?

Edit to add: If I change the `ZoneId.of("GMT")` and change JUST IT to `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, the ending result is as expected and 'correct'. (i.e. Stays Jan 1st 1934.)

Comment: How and where are you seeing that your time zone is taken into account? (Asking because it is not.)

Comment: @OleV.V. I didn't think the Date object had any 'timezone' info at all - however, when I look in Android Studio during debugging, there is a field part of the Date object that contains the zone offset time. (The name of said field at the moment escapes me - will need to pull it up once I'm back in the office tomorrow.)

Comment: Ir’s correct, the implementation of `Date` often stores a time zone. I have never understood why, it’s very confusing. One guess is that it is an optimization thing. I have never seen a case where it differed from the JVM default time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device or JVM time zone is *not* taken into account in the conversion itself.

The `Date` class is confusing. Despite its name it does not represent a date, nor a date and time of day. It represents a moment in time, a point in time, an instant. As you probably know, Jan 1st, 1934 00:00 GMT is the same point in time as Dec 31st, 1933, 7pm. in America/New_York time zone. This means that you are getting a correct conversion. And more than that: it means that you are getting *the only* possible correct conversion. Any other conversion to a `Date` would have given you a different point in time, that is, a wrong point in time.

What may have confused you could be that if you try to use your `Date` for something, that something could well assume that you intended the default time zone of your JVM and device. For example if you print out the `Date` or view it in your debugger, in both cases implicitly invoking its `toString` method, then that `toString` method uses your time zone to render the string that you see:

> Sun Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1933

`toString()` is telling a lie. I would have us believe that the `Date` contains that value. It does not. It contains a count of milliseconds since the Java epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC. In your case a negative count since your point in time is before the epoch, -1 136 073 600 000 milliseconds. Nothing else.

**The solution?** It depends on what you need at `Date` for and what the requirements for that `Date` are. Ideally you should not need a `Date` since that class is poorly designed and long outdated. You would be better off using exclusively classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API to which `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId` belong. If you do need a `Date`, maybe you have already got the right one and just need to clear your confusion and settle with it. If you give us reason and the requirements, we can probably guide you better.

**Link:** [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) on Jon Skeet’s coding blog

Comment: Thanks for the thgouth-out answer. At this time I (believe) I am stuck with the Date object as the value is ending up being stored in an ObjectBox database, as a 'Date' type. Other types (like `LocalDate`, which actually would fit better as well, and is what I started with) needs a custom converter hooked up, to save the value as a base type. (String, Int, etc.)

Comment: I don’t know ObjectBox. If I understand [this page](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types) correctly, ObjectBox stores the millisecond value I mentioned, so you should be set, I guess. I’d still prefer to get rid of the confusing `Date` class and store for example `Instant` from java.time even if it means writing a custom converter.

Comment: You recommend an `Instant` or a `LocalDate`? I note the latter only stores the date, which is all that's important in this use-case. If I gotta write a converter, I will. :)

Comment: Yes, in that case a `LocalDate`, you are right. The *local* in the class name means *without time zone*.